# rasterFromXYZ, which corner is selecting?

Tags: raster, r, csv

I am using the rasterFromXYZ function of the package raster because I want to convert a xyz (lon, lat, value) .csv file into a raster file. In the .csv, I have the information of the bottom left hand corner of the grid cell, but when I apply the function there is no argument to specify this information.

Which corner is selecting the rasterFromXYZ funtion? How can I specify a different one?

The code I am using is:

```
df <- df <- data.frame(x = a$lon,
             y = a$lat,
             z = a$fh)

ps_raster <- rasterFromXYZ(df, res=c(0.01,0.01),crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", digits=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`rasterFromXYZ` will assume your x, y are the *centres* of the cells. So, you can offset them by half a cell in each direction before running the function, or modify the resulting extent afterwards.

Not sure it's written explicitly, but you can infer it - the `extent()` is corner-based, but the `coordinates()` are centres.

`coordinates(raster(extent(0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 5, ncol = 5))`

`rasterFromXYZ` is really the inverse of `coordinates()` or `as.data.frame(, xy = TRUE)`

Comment: Where have you found this information. I am not able to find it in the Rhelp. Thanks @mdsummer.

Comment: I added a little more